# ast.literal_eval: Unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, temporary-files

I am trying to parse an array, which is stored as a string in a `tempfile.TemporaryFile`, back into an array using `ast.literal_eval`. My (simplified) code looks like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

# a TemporaryFile temp_file gets created and filled with some arrays.

temp_file.seek(0)
for line in temp_file.read():
    line = literal_eval(line)
    for element in line:
        print element.decode('utf-8')
temp_file.close()
```

The contents of the `temp_file` look like this (if the `literal_eval` call is removed):

```
['Hello', 'World', '123']
['Unicode', u'\xf6\xf6\xe4\xe4', u'??!!\xdf\xdf']
```

Whenever I try to add the `literal_eval` call back in, Python throws the following `SyntaxError`:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1544, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    b = Button(self.frame_below_right,text="Yealink Code generieren",command=lambda *args:self.scanGrid(self.frame_table))
  File "test.py", line 137, in scanGrid
    line = literal_eval(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I am aware, that I have to be careful with `ast.literal_eval`. Nonetheless Is there a more appropriate tool for the job than `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: `for line in temp_file.read():` => `for line in temp_file:` or you're just reading character by character

Comment: BTW what is `current_line` ??

Comment: `current_line` is supposed to mean just `line`. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line is *very wrong*:

```
for line in temp_file.read():
```

`temp_file.read()` returns the full file *contents*. Now `line` is a character, which explains why `literal_eval` prints a syntax error on the first `[` alone.

You want to iterate on the lines, simply:

```
for line in temp_file:
    line = literal_eval(line)
```

> I am aware, that I have to be careful with ast.literal_eval. Is there a more apropriate tool for the job than ast.literal_eval?

You're mixing this up with `eval()` which is unsafe because it evaluates anything, including statements deleting your whole harddrive. `ast.literal_eval` evalulates only *literals*, so it's perfectly safe, albeit limited (you cannot pass too complex expressions like multiplications, etc...), but in your case, you just deserialize a dump, so it's a perfect fit.

(note that `json.loads` wouldn't work here because of the single quotes, and the `u` prefix which is python-specific)